# How to count frequency of a word without counting compound words in bash?

Tags: bash, grep, counting

I am using this to count the frequency in a text file using bash.

`grep -ow -i "and" $1 | wc -l`

It counts all the **and** in the file, including those that are part of compound words, like **jerry-and-jeorge**. These I wish to ignore and count all other independent **and**.

Comment: Use `grep -oP -i "(?<!\S)and(?!\S)" $1 | wc -l`

Comment: I get ```bash: !\S: event not found```

Comment: Sorry, `grep -oP -i '(?<!\S)and(?!\S)' $1 | wc -l`

Comment: Please, post some sample data with the related expected output.
Don't post them as comments, images, tables or links to off-site
services but use text and include them to your original question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a GNU grep, you can use the following command to count `and` words that are not enclosed with hyphens:

```sh
grep -ioP '\b(?<!-)and\b(?!-)' "$1" | wc -l
```

*Details*:

- `P` option enables the PCRE regex syntax
- `\b(?<!-)and\b(?!-)` matches

  - `\b` - a word boundary
  - `(?<!-)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a hyphen immediately to the left of the current location
  - `and` - a fixed string
  - `\b` - a word boundary
  - `(?!-)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a hyphen immediately to the right of the current location.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/NHo6aW):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='jerry-and-jeorge, and, aNd, And.'
grep -ioP '\b(?<!-)and\b(?!-)' <<< "$s" | wc -l
# => 3 (not 4)
```